# converting date time string to date with time in R

Tags: r, csv, time

When I read in my .csv file, and convert start_date from a string, the date is fine, but it seems to drop the time

my csv file looks like this:

```
SAMPNUM,SITE,VISITNUM,entered_order,method,start_date,start_crew,end_date,end_crew
2002,165,4,736,leaf_litter,8/17/11 0:00,FSA,NA,NA
2003,172,4,737,leaf_litter,8/17/11 0:00,FSA,NA,NA
5004,122,4,21,pitfall,8/17/11 12:15,ADY SJT PSA JRW SWH,9/2/11 0:00,ADY
5005,123,4,22,pitfall,8/17/11 13:00,ADY SJT PSA JRW SWH,9/2/11 0:00,ADY
```

I first read in the file:

```
sample<-read.csv('SampleType.csv', header = TRUE, na.strings=c("NA",""))
```

which seems to read in fine, my data looks like:

```
2002    165 4   736 leaf_litter 8/17/11 0:00    FSA NA  NA
2003    172 4   737 leaf_litter 8/17/11 0:00    FSA NA  NA
5004    122 4   21  pitfall 8/17/11 12:15   ADY SJT PSA JRW SWH 9/2/11 0:00 ADY
5005    123 4   22  pitfall 8/17/11 13:00   ADY SJT PSA JRW SWH 9/2/11 0:00 ADY
```

but when I try to convert date/time, I'm stuck.  I've tried lost of stuff, but my best is:

```
sample$start_date <- as.Date(sample$start_date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
sample$end_date <- as.Date(sample$end_date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

this leaves my data looking like:

```
2002    165 4   736 leaf_litter 15203   FSA NA  NA
2003    172 4   737 leaf_litter 15203   FSA NA  NA
5004    122 4   21  pitfall 15203   ADY SJT PSA JRW SWH 15219   ADY
5005    123 4   22  pitfall 15203   ADY SJT PSA JRW SWH 15219   ADY
```

but when I look at values

> sample$start_date[3]

I get:

[1] "2011-08-17"

why isn't it giving the time of day?

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, such a novice....  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You convert to class `Date`, which by definition does not contain times. Look at `?strptime` or `?as.POSIXct`.

Comment: I've looked at these, but can't figure out how to get them to work:    `sample$start_date <- as.POSIXct(sample$start_date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`      doesn't do it, nor does `sample$start_date <- strptime(sample$start_date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: Check out the `lubridate` package which handles date objects in a very natural/sensible way.

Comment: Thanks looks like `lubridate` would be an easier way for a beginner (such as me) to deal with date-time issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`:

```
as.POSIXct("9/2/11 4:20", format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M",tz="GMT")
#[1] "2011-09-02 04:20:00 GMT"

strptime("9/2/11 4:20", format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M",tz="GMT")
#[1] "2011-09-02 04:20:00 GMT"
```

Class `Date` does not contain information on the time of the day by definition.

Comment: That did it, thank you!   `sample$start_date <- as.POSIXct(sample$start_date, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: I really recommend to set the time zone explicitly. Otherwise you probably will run into trouble with daylight saving time sooner or later.